# Tag synonyms new-latin, neo-latin

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think we should synonymize or merge these two tags ([neo-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo-latin) and [new-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-latin)), unless I'm missing some nuance. I already suggested the synonym.

Tag [new-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-latin) has more questions (112). Maybe some could argue that [neo-latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo-latin) (20) should be favored as more cultured. (Or there could be another naming convention in play that I'm missing?)

Comment: Good catch! I tend to agree, but I'd like to see a couple of more opinions (as votes or otherwise) before proceeding to merge. At least we can synonymize quickly, but merging (which is a fuller way to identify the two tags) sounds reasonable too.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta hmm, didn't know that. After merging, does auto-complete keep suggesting the synonym, or would someone typing 'neo' see no 'new-latin' suggestion? (Assuming the merger goes in favor of the latter.)

Comment: I think whatever suggestions happen after synonymization will continue to happen after merging. In synonymization the two tags continue to coexist but are considered equivalent, whereas in merging one is removed and replaced with the other (and will continue to be replaced after the merge). [Our list of tag synonyms](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is public (albeit hard to find), but I'm not sure if non-moderators see which ones have been merged and which ones not.

Comment: I agree with your proposal. We'll still wait a tiny bit to hear other ideas, but I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I think that would be a good idea. I am used to the term Neo-Latin, so that is what I would prefer for the tag. But I think I have also seen the translation New Latin used, so that is probably also acceptable, if others know it is used in academic texts as well?

Comment: Given that we can reverse the order of a synonymization later, the stakes are low. We should go and approve the suggested synonym, if you haven't already.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Ah, done.